# JSON.stringify() across all browsers?

Tags: javascript, json, html

How can I get a cross-all-browser version of JSON.stringify()?

I want it to accept all three parameters:

```
JSON.stringify(value [, replacer] [, space])
```

And return the same result in every major browser.

Comment: In which browsers do you experience differences?

Comment: I wasn't aware the `JSON.stringify` has additional optional parameters, but the function itself should be available in all major browsers, so what's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I've understood your question correctly, anyway in the past I've used [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) by Douglas Crockford,
to have `JSON.parse`/`JSON.stringify` on Internet Explorer LT8.

Comment: Does not help though if `JSON.stringfy` itself produces different outputs. I don't know if that's even the case, that's why I asked.

Comment: If anything: https://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/ :)